# Instagram Graph API Authorizing IG user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I am using the INSTAGRAM GRAPH API and I want to authorize Instagram Business Users with our APP so that i can GRAB their insights. I have checked the documentation, they showing manual way to attach Instagram account by going to Facebook page settings. Please let me know if can be achieved via authorize with Instagram Account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first make your Instagram account a business account. This can be done in the Instagram Mobile app under settings.

Next, you need to connect your Instagram business account to a Facebook Page. This must be done manually by the user.

https://help.instagram.com/570895513091465

After the Facebook Page is connected, you can then use the IG API to [authorize](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/oauth-authorize/) your user and then get [insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/insights/) on their accounts/posts. Be sure to the user grants the right [permissions](https://docs.ayrshare.com/gui-dashboard/connect-social-media/instagram-linking) to get insights.

Please note, you need the right permissions from Facebook and need to go through their [review process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will implement the solution.

Comment: The below URL works for the Instagram Basic Display API. But I am using the GRAPH API
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/oauth-authorize/ 

When I trigger the authorize URL, It gives me error "{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid platform app"}" because the CLient ID I am using is of the FACEBOOK APP not the INSTAGRAM APP. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @user9094763, You got that error because the [authorize URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/oauth-authorize/)  only works for the Instagram Basic Display API which is for read-only operation by the way. The authentication used by the Instagram Graph API is the user's Facebook account token. That means the Instagram account must be connected to that same Facebook account. A Facebook page is also required. You can read [Instagram graph API overview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview) for more info on authentication.